# use effect and requestController.abort

Tags: reactjs

When I try to fetch data, the Catch error block, is triggered automatically.
I know it comes from " return requestController.abort();".
I read that it was necessary to add an abort to cancel the request if the user decides to change pages suddenly. should i delete it? thank you a lot :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8SuO.png)

```
const fetchDefinition = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${word}`,
      { signal }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error();
    }
    let data = await response.json();
    setDefinition(data);
    setisLoading(false);
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error is", error);
    setExist(false);
  }
};

fetchDefinition();
return () => {
  return requestController.abort();
};}, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is most likely because of React's `StrictMode`, which mounts, unmounts and then re-mounts your component on purpose to detect any potential issues within your React app. You can read more about this on the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

Since your component is unmounting, then the `abort()` method of the `controller` is executing as expected in your `useEffect`'s cleanup function.

You could remove `StrictMode` and your problem would be solved, but this is generally not a good idea/practice (it's there for a reason, after all) and if remounting breaks the logic of your app, then there is definitely something wrong with it.

What you can do is check for the `error.name` and don't perform any action if it's `AbortError`, or you can also check the `controller.signal.aborted` flag. After all, when this happens, the component is unmounted at this point anyways.

```
try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${word}`,
      { signal }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error();
    }
    let data = await response.json();
    setDefinition(data);
    setisLoading(false);
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name !== "AbortError") { // Or if (!controller.signal.aborted)
    console.log("error is", error);
    setExist(false);
   }
  }
};
```